# Dimension of irreducible variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Why is the dimension of intersection, $V\cap H$, of $m$-dimensional irreducible variety $V$ and a hyperplane given by $\dim(V\cap H)$ of dimension $m-1$?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't always have to be $m-1$, but it must be at least dimension $m-1$. This is essentially the content of Krull's principal ideal theorem together with the fact that you for a finite type $k$-algebra $A$, one has that $\dim A/\mathfrak{p}+\text{ht}(\mathfrak{p})=\dim A$.

Comment: @Turbo $V\cap H$ is cut out of $\text{Spec}(A)=V$ by $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: So $\mathfrak p=(x_i-a)=I(H)$ (ideal generated by the hyperplane)?

Comment: Alex, by irreducibility either the hyperplane contains $V$, or the dimension is actually $m-1$.  An ideal generated by a non-zerodivisor can't have height $0$.

Comment: @Turbo Yes, it's essentially what Phil says. It will reduce the dimension by $1$, unless it's contained in the plane. Does that make sense? Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @Phil Yes, of course. I should have said how it can be $m$. Thanks!

Comment: @Turbo Define classic? Intuitively the dimension is the amount of parameters needed to define the space. Intersecting with a hyperplane reduces the amount of parameters by $1$ since the hyperplane imposes the condition that $x_i=0$ (whichever $x_i$ $V$ corresponds to) and so $x_i$ is no longer a free parameter.

Comment: true but we could have a $m$-dimensional variety in $n$ variables. $x_i$ could be an 'unimportant' coordinate.

Comment: @Turbo Then, by irreducibility it would be the full thing.

Comment: So you are saying $m$ hyperplanes could could a variety (since each reduces dimension by $1$)?

Comment: @Turbo No, irreducibility will perhaps fail after you hit it with the first hyperplane.